# ¿Existe en swift algo como el raw_input de python?

Tags: swift

¿Se puede hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
nombre = raw_input("cual es tu nombre?")
```

para que coja la respuesta del usuario desde un `textfield` o desde la consola?

Comment: yo de swift no tengo ni idea, pero te comento esto hasta que obtengas respuesta, quizas ayude, quizas en la Clase textfield tenga un metodo al cual puedas acceder para obtener el string que se encuentre en el textfield, si fuera como Java por ejemplo buscaria alguno de sus famosos get, algo asi por ejemplo tuTexfield.getInput(); . Mirando por encima creo que puedes usar tuTexfield.text pero no se si eso es una variable o un metodo espero ayude Saludos

Comment: textfield.text se usa para "escribir" en un texfield

Comment: no te lo voy a discustir pues yo de Switf ni idea pero quizas actue como una propiedad o algo parecido en C# a la cual puedes tambien tener acceso self.tuTexfield.text  Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera he consigo que me funcione desde el mismo Xcode y puedo introducir el valor sin error por consola, es prácticamente el mismo código que el anterior pero cambiando alguna cosilla.

```
func input() -> NSString{
    let teclado = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = teclado.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
var operacion:String = input() as String
```

Answer (score 2):

Para asignar el contenido de un `UITextField` solo tienes que utilizar la propiedad `text`:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    // otros métodos y variables

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let valorIngresado = textField.text;
    }
}
```

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar un script en la consola, no hay un método para leer directamente un valor desde teclado, pero es posible implementarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
// Archivo script.swift
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
import Foundation

// Esta función se encarga de leer desde la entrada estándar (teclado)
// Y regresa el dato como una cadena
func readLine() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}

let cadena = readLine()
print(cadena)
```

Y ejecutarlo con

```
$ ./script.swift
```

Es necesario ejecutar este ejemplo como un script, no funciona en playgrounds.

El código para leer de teclado aparece originalmente [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application)

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo.

Comment: Me dice **./script.swift: command not found** pero no se que me da el error.

Comment: Asegúrate que te encuentres en la misma ruta del script y tenga permisos de ejecución

Comment: Estoy en la ruta y ejecuto el script con sudo, no se si debería de darle algún permiso al archivo en si, porque sigue el error

Answer (score 1):

Veo que puedo hacer algo así para usarlo con Xcode:

```
let dato = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))

dato.placeholder = "Introduzca un valor"
```

De esta manera formulo lo que quiero preguntar en el mismo `textfield`. Aunque para consola no valga claro.